# How to run commands in postgres inside docker using python script?

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

I have wrote a script to download a postgresql image in docker and run certain commands inside the docker.

I am able to successfully download the container and enter inside it after getting the container id using script.

```py
import subprocess, os
import docker
import time

def run_command(command):
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
    
def execute_command_in_container(container_id, command):
    client = docker.from_env()

    try:
        # Start the container if not already running
        container = client.containers.get(container_id)
        container.start()

        # Execute the command inside the container
        exec_result = container.exec_run(command, stdout=True, stderr=True, tty=True)

        # Print the command output      
        print("Command output:")
        print(exec_result.output.decode())

        # Print the command error, if any
        if exec_result.exit_code != 0:
            print("Command error:")
            print(exec_result.stderr.decode())

    except docker.errors.NotFound as e:
        print(f"Container with ID {container_id} not found.")
    except docker.errors.APIError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while communicating with Docker API: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        if container:
            container.stop()

# Pull PostgreSQL image
pull_image_command = "docker pull postgres"
run_command(pull_image_command)

run_container_command = "docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d -p 5432:5432 postgres"
run_command(run_container_command)

get_container_id_command = "docker ps -qf 'name=postgres'"
result = subprocess.run(get_container_id_command, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
container_id = result.stdout.strip()

sql_dump_path = "/Users/dump.sql"
if not os.path.exists(sql_dump_path):
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"The file {sql_dump_path} does not exist.")


copy_to_container_command = f"docker cp {sql_dump_path} {container_id}:/"
run_command(copy_to_container_command)

# code fails from here till the end
commands_within_container = [
    "psql -U postgres",
]

enter_container_and_execute_commands = f"docker exec -it {container_id} bash"
run_command(enter_container_and_execute_commands)
for command in commands_within_container:
    execute_command_in_container(container_id, command)
    time.sleep(2)
    
commands_within_container = [
     "CREATE DATABASE abc;",
     .
     .
     .
     .
    
]

for command in commands_within_container:
    execute_command_in_container(container_id, command)
 
commands_within_container_2 = [
    .
    .
    . 
    .
    
    "\q"
]
for command in commands_within_container_2:
    execute_command_in_container(container_id, command)


last_command = "psql -U postgres abc < dump.sql"
run_command(last_command)

run_command("exit")
```

Code stops here, this is the terminal output:

```
Successfully copied 5.69GB to 69be84c9269:/
root@69be84c9269:/#
```

I need to make tables inside the postgresql as per my dump. How to fix my script accordingly?

Comment: The `docker exec -it {container_id} bash` will block. You are actually seeing its shell prompt. Try without that call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an ordinary PostgreSQL client library, like [psycopg](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg/).  When you start your database, make sure you have a `docker run -p` or Compose `ports:` option that makes the database port visible to the host.  Configure your application to connect to the published port.

**You do not need to do anything Docker-specific to interact with the database.  You do not need `docker exec` in routine use.**

Let's say you have run **outside your script** the command you show to start the container

```bash
docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

Now, assuming your script is running on the host, you can access the database on `localhost:5432`.  That port number matches the first `-p` port number, the second `-p` port number must be the standard PostgreSQL port 5432.  This works like any other psycopg program

```py
sql_commands = [
     "CREATE DATABASE abc;",
     ...
]
with psycopg.connect('host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=mysecretpassword') as conn:
  for command in sql_commands:
   with conn.cursor() as cur:
     cur.execute(command)
```

Note that this is the exact same script (up to the connection string) that you'd run to interact with a non-container database, or a cloud-hosted database like Amazon RDS, or to interact with a PostgreSQL database running in a separate container in a common Compose setup.

You can similarly directly use `psql` or `pgrestore` on the host system, talking to the published database port, without doing anything Docker-specific.

The overall setup you're describing here is not that different from a database-migration setup (you'll typically create tables in a migration script, for example).  And again, since you don't need to do anything Docker-specific to interact with the database, you can run an ordinary migration system to create and update the tables in the database.